# Reset atq list to zero?

Tags: at

I have been using `at` for quite a while now, and I noticed that the `at` job ids seem to increment forever.

```
$ atq
332 Mon Sep 23 17:25:00 2013 a cklein
$ # I'm up to 332 at jobs!
```

Interestingly, `at` doesn't seem to keep around data about completed jobs.

```
$ at -c 331
Cannot find jobid 331
```

Is it possible to reset this job id number back to 0?

Comment: Without rebooting I assume?

Comment: I don't think you can do this without either restarting the service or a reboot.

Comment: For some reason I can't restart my `atd` service, I get a `start: Rejected send message...` error. Do you think that restarting the service would reset that number?

Comment: I don't think so, but you could do something like this, t
ake a look at this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304631/rescheduling-an-at-job

Comment: A better question might be _why_ you want to do this. Are you trying to achieve something specific (in which case there may be a better way) or is this idle curiosity (nothing wrong with that of course)?

Comment: @terdon Naw, it's just idle curiosity. I was curious that none of the files in `FILES` section of `man at` seemed to have a reference to this identifier, so I wondered where the number could possibly come from?

Comment: @terdon I saw something where I thought "hmm, I don't understand how that works!" but I couldn't figure it out on my own, so I came here!

Comment: Always good to ask questions, @terdon, if you want to write it up as the answer feel free.

Comment: That was not a rebuke, idle curiosity is great and very welcome, bring it on! I just wanted to make sure this was not an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). Anyway, since `atd` is a demon, I imagine it simply counts the number of commands it has run since its launch and uses that as its job number. I don't see anything very strange in that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A restart of the `atd` service did not reset the job id as we suspected:

#### Example

*some test submissions*

```
$ at -f test.bash now
job 105 at Mon Sep 23 20:04:00 2013
$ at -f test.bash now
job 106 at Mon Sep 23 20:04:00 2013
```

*double checking the spool dir*

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/spool/at/spool/
total 0
```

*a restart of atd*

$ sudo /etc/init.d/atd restart
Stopping atd:                                              [  OK  ]
Starting atd:                                              [  OK  ]

*subsequent test submissions*

```
$ at -f test.bash now
job 107 at Mon Sep 23 20:05:00 2013
$ at -f test.bash now
job 108 at Mon Sep 23 20:05:00 2013
```

#### Digging deeper

So if you look at the executable `atd` with a tool such as `lsof` you'll notice the following:

```
$ sudo lsof | grep atd
atd       22341      root  cwd       DIR              253,0      4096    2103653 /var/spool/at
atd       22341      root  rtd       DIR              253,0      4096          2 /
atd       22341      root  txt       REG              253,0     24712    1192814 /usr/sbin/atd
atd       22341      root  mem       REG              253,0     57440     393478 /lib64/libnss_files-2.13.so
atd       22341      root  mem       REG              253,0    387352     393694 /lib64/libfreebl3.so
atd       22341      root  mem       REG              253,0     43304     393695 /lib64/libcrypt-2.13.so
atd       22341      root  mem       REG              253,0     99128     393328 /lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0
atd       22341      root  mem       REG              253,0     22536     393671 /lib64/libdl-2.13.so
atd       22341      root  mem       REG              253,0   1956608     393664 /lib64/libc-2.13.so
atd       22341      root  mem       REG              253,0     13776     393333 /lib64/libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
atd       22341      root  mem       REG              253,0     55280     393331 /lib64/libpam.so.0.82.2
atd       22341      root  mem       REG              253,0    124592     393682 /lib64/libselinux.so.1
atd       22341      root  mem       REG              253,0    151456     393578 /lib64/ld-2.13.so
atd       22341      root    0u      CHR                1,3       0t0       4066 /dev/null
atd       22341      root    1u      CHR                1,3       0t0       4066 /dev/null
atd       22341      root    2u      CHR                1,3       0t0       4066 /dev/null
atd       22341      root    3uW     REG              253,0         6    1966556 /var/run/atd.pid
```

#### Investigating the spool dir.

So there isn't any file open, but  there is a directory, `/var/spool/at`, so let's investigate a little bit further in there:

```
$ sudo ls -la /var/spool/at/
total 20
drwx------.  3 daemon daemon 4096 Sep 23 20:42 .
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root   root   4096 Aug  8  2011 ..
-rw-------.  1 daemon daemon    6 Sep 23 20:05 .SEQ
drwx------.  2 daemon daemon 4096 Sep 23 20:42 spool
```

Bingo! There's the thing we're looking for, a file called `.SEQ`. More the file shows this:

```
$ sudo more .SEQ 
0006c
```

We can convince ourselves of the fact that this is the right value using `bc` to convert this from hex to decimal:

```
$ echo "ibase=16; 0006C"|bc
108
```

#### An experiment

Appears to be putting the number here in hex. We can do a little experiment and change this value to a 0. But first stop the `atd` service.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/atd stop
...edit file using vim, change it to 0...
$ sudo /etc/init.d/atd start
```

Now run another test of `at`:

```
$ at -f test.bash now
job 1 at Mon Sep 23 20:52:00 2013
```

And the number has restarted, we're back to 1. If I stop, edit, start it again and put the value `0006c` back in:

```
$ at -f test.bash now
job 109 at Mon Sep 23 20:53:00 2013
```

Mystery solved.

#### A note on other distros

The above was sleuthed on a Fedora system, other distros such as Debian & Ubuntu may store the `.SEQ` file in an entirely different directory. For example Ubuntu stores the file like this:

```
$ sudo pwd
/var/spool/cron/atjobs
$ sudo ls -la
total 12
drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon 4096 Sep 23 21:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root   4096 Oct 17  2012 ..
-rw------- 1 daemon daemon    6 Sep 23 21:19 .SEQ
```